# HTML5 progress element not rendering any child elements?

Tags: html, dom, google-chrome

Code is:

```
 <progress max="100" value="100">100%</progress>
```

That `100%` either wrapped in span tags, p's, div's, other progresses, nothing ever makes it get displayed. On both Chrome and Opera, running on W7x64.

Is this default behavior? Should I write on top of the progress bar with `position:absolute`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the content inside the `<progress>` tag is fallback for browsers who don't support HTML5.

http://lea.verou.me/2011/07/a-polyfill-for-html5-progress-element-the-obsessive-perfectionist-way/

Answer (score 1):

The inner content of a `<progress>` will only render in browsers that do not
support it.This is similar behavior to `<video>`, `<canvas>`, etc. Both Chrome and Opera support `<progress>`.

If you want to render the percentage alongside the progress bar itself, try to 
use ::after and data attributes. Sort of a poor man's data binding:

```
<style>
#progress:after {
  content: attr(data-percent) '%';
  margin-left: 5px;
}
</style>

<div id="progress" data-percent="10">
  <progress max="100" value="10" min="0"></progress>
</div>
```

You'd have to add an change listener to update `data-percent` when the progress's
value changes.

See:
http://jsbin.com/asuqow/edit#html,live

Comment: But I can't directly bind the value attribute of the child <progress> element can I? The point was I wanted it to show up centered, on top of the progress bar, black with a white shadow. And when updating the progress bar, it would only need `$('progress').val(12)` something.